# What Type of ANOVA Design is it?

Tags: self-study, anova, repeated-measures, spss

> There are two different type of games (PC and Console), and each game is played on two different screen sizes: 9 inches and 27 inches. 50 subjects are recruited to play the PC game on both screen sizes. One will start on the small screen size for 15 min and then play on the bigger screen size for 15 min, and second subject will start on the big screen and then shift onto the small screen, and so on.
>
> Another 50 subjects are recruited to play the Console game, first on the big screen and then on the small screen, and so on.
>
> The dependent variable is fun.
>
> The 100 participants who played the PC and the Console games are screened into two groups of expertise - novice and expert. The researcher wants to examine if both novice and expert players will derive the same amount of fun (dependent var).

Below is my rationale; kindly advise if I am in the right direction.

It is 3-way mixed ANOVA Design with 3 independent var: Expertise (in-between subject tests with two levels: (novice and expert), and Type of Games (in-between subject tests with two levels: PC and Console), and Screen Size (within-subject tests with two levels: 9 and 17 inches).

I plan to enter the data into spss as shown below.

**(i) I can see the design as a MANOVA, with two independent var, groups and game types, and two dependent var: "fun" score for (9" and 27" screen sizes). Please advise if this logic is correct.**

**(ii) Alternatively, I am not sure if the design can be considered a 3-way mixed  ANOVA, with 2 in-between subject test (groups (2 levels) and game types (2 levels)), and within-subject test - screen sizes (2 levels).  However, the dependent var data (fun score) for each screen size are displayed in the two columns - 9" and 27" screen sizes.**

**(iii) A third thought, it looks like a Multivariate Regression, with two dependent var (fun score for 9" and 27"), and two independent var. The issue is I have data for only (novice and expert) following the use of a screening questionnaire.**

Kindly advise which of the above options are most appropriate.

[image: Visual Representation of Data]

**FIGURE 1**

Comment: I have provided a visual representation of my data. I would like to know if it is indeed a 3-way ANOVA design, with 3 independent var: (i) groups - 2 levels (ii) game types -2 levels (iii)  screen size - 2 levels. How do we represent the data into SPSS? I am not sure about the game types - as PC and Consoles are subsets of both novice and expert category. I have shown the data (dependent var) as "fun score." Kindly advise.

Comment: The last part - as a question about how to use SPSS: "*How do we display the data in SPSS?*" - is [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (see under Programming). [However I think it's looking for a way to display data that would allow some visual comparison relevant to the questions of interest (perhaps some display that would allow some kind of comparisons of group means for example) -- I don't think the image under that question is what it's looking for]

Comment: The objective is to find out if novice and expert (groups) influence the fun score. In other words, if both novice and experts experience the same or different level of fun, on a particular screen size. Kindly advise which ANOVA design should I adopt. I was also thinking of a Regression, but with two different fun scores for two screen sizes, not sure how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend Option II. Although any ANOVA design can be done with regression, repeated measures designs are relatively complex to set up (and it set up correctly you would  get same answer as ANOVA). How to manipulate  the data format to allow a repeated-measures ANOVA is a good topic  for another forum.

Comment: OK. I understand that a 3-Way mixed ANOVA is appropriate in this case. (1) Referring to the attached Figure 1 above, can you advise if I am using the right variable (screen size) - independent var or should it be the dependent var (fun score), since the values under 9" and 27" are actually the response var (fun score). (2) if a regression analysis is performed, and the p-value is significant, r will tell us the strength of the relationship between novice and fun; expert and fun. It is the mean value which will answer the research question, if experts or novices derive higher level of fun. thx